# Is it possible to list all files in a *.tar.gz file without scanning it's whole contents?

Tags: tar, gzip

I know this way only:

```
tar --full-time -tvf /path/to/file.tar.gz
```

But it makes tar to scan all the archive and it is time consuming if it is a very big one. My question is maybe there is a way to scan only beginning, only header of some sort just as it happens in other formats like *.7z or *.rar ?

Comment: There's no table of contents in a `tar` archive. The metadata for each file is before the file.

Comment: That command will not work with that file (assuming that the file extension is correct). You need an `a`, as it is compressed. Also, because it is compressed the program can to skip, it must read every byte (if there is any redundancy in a compressed file, then it is not compressed well).

Comment: `a` ?, 1) what does it do ? I can't find it on man page ( http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html ), there is an `-A` option but for concatenating archive at the end. 2) what I wrote in question works.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no."

`7Zip`, RAR, `zip`, *et al.*, are all dual-function programs/file formats. They compress individual files, then archive the compressed results. That results in portions of the file that are **not** compressed, but that, in turn, allows programs to get to individual files.

`gzip` (the `.gz` part) is different. It compresses a single byte stream only. The byte stream is provided by `tar`. `bzip2` (`.bz2`) does the same thing, though with a different algorithm. `tar` is the archiver program, and `gzip` is the compression program. In order to get to the archive at all, the stream must **first** be decompressed. That can only happen by going through the **entire file**. Then, and only then, can `tar` get to the individual pieces of the archive.

The reason you don't see the `gzip` step here is that it has been built into `tar`, not directly *per se*, but by `tar` knowing to pipe its output stream to `gzip`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#File_format) for a description of the format of a tar file. Basically, it's just an alternating sequence of *file header* and *file contents*. There's no table of contents at the beginning, all the information about each file is in its *file header*.

The header includes the file size, so when just listing the contents the reader may be able to skip reading all the contents blocks by seeking to the beginning of the next header. However, if the tar file is compressed that isn't possible, because it first has to uncompress the contents so it can skip the appropriate number of uncompressed bytes.